# ASP.NET, object data source 5+ rows returned - force repeater to only show one

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way with ASP.NET to tell a data repeater which is working against a objectDataSource to only show the first row and not any others that are returned in the objectDataSource.

I can't limit the data source to one row as it's echo'ing to a grid above the repeater.

Forgive me if this is a stupid question!

Thanks in advance

C

Comment: Thanks for the type fix Ahmad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your repeater event handler you can use the event object to see what number the item in the collection you are on.

So you can say if that number > 0 or 1 or whatever it is, render, if not, do nothing.

It's been a really long time since I've used .NET, but I know you can lookup the index of the item in the ItemDataBound event.

Comment: Great, this got me to the answer. I used the ItemDataBound as you suggested and then added this method in the code behind

protected void ForceStopAfterFirstBind(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemIndex > 0)
        {
            e.Item.Controls.Clear();
        }
    }